# Сортировка Collections

Tags: java

Как сделать сортировку всех ArrayList?

```
package com.company;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

abstract class Product {

protected Long ean;
protected Double price;
protected String name;

public Product (String name, Double price, Long ean) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.ean = ean;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public Long getEan() {
    return ean;
}
}

class Food extends Product {

    private int cal;
    private Date creationDate;
    private int expirationTime;

    public Food(String name, Double price, Long ean, int cal, Date creationDate, int expirationTime) {
        super(name, price, ean);
        this.cal = cal;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCal() {
        return cal;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public int ExpirationTime() {
        return expirationTime;
    }


    public String toString() {
        return name+", "+price+" руб. , "+ean+", "+cal+" кКал, "+creationDate+" д.с. , "+expirationTime+" до с.и.";
    }
}

class Appliance extends Product{

private int inputPower;

public Appliance(String name, Double price, Long ean, int inputPower) {
    super(name, price, ean);
    this.inputPower = inputPower;
}
public String toString() {
    return name+", "+price+" руб. , "+ean+", "+inputPower+" Ват";
}

public int getInputPower() {
    return inputPower;
}

}

class Clothes extends Product{

private byte size;
private String material;

public Clothes(String name, Double price, Long ean, byte size, String material) {
    super(name, price, ean);
    this.material = material;
    this.size = size;
}
public String toString() {
    return name+", "+price+" руб. , "+ean+", "+size+", "+material;
}

public byte getSize() {
    return size;
}

public String getMaterial() {
    return material;
}
}

class warehouse {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

    String SCzCh = "28.06.2019";
    Date SC = date.parse(SCzCh);

    String Slosos = "30.06.2019";
    Date SL = date.parse(Slosos);

    String Ekler = "29.06.2019";
    Date El = date.parse(Ekler);

    String Borsh = "30.06.2019";
    Date Bs = date.parse(Borsh);

    String Cake = "27.06.2019";
    Date Ck = date.parse(Cake);

    List <Food> all = new ArrayList<>();


    List<Food> food = new ArrayList<>();
          Food SCzCh1 = new Food( "Салат Цезарь с курицей", 250.0, 9031101L, 370, SC, 4);
          Food Slosos1 = new Food( "Сандвич с лососем", 40.0, 9043243L, 494, SL, 2);
          Food Ekler1 = new Food( "Эклер", 150.0, 9054324L, 236, El, 5);
          Food Borsh1 = new Food ( "Борщ", 250.0, 9045435L, 679, Bs, 4);
          Food Cake1 =  new Food( "Медовик", 226.0, 9042353L, 1534, Ck, 29);

    food.add(SCzCh1);
    food.add(Slosos1);
    food.add(Ekler1);
    food.add(Borsh1);
    food.add(Cake1);

    List<Appliance> apl = new ArrayList<>();
            Appliance Toster = new Appliance("Тостер", 1990.0, 2054355L, 850);
            Appliance Fridge = new Appliance("Холодильник", 15000.0, 2043242L, 400);
            Appliance Blender = new Appliance("Блендер", 4299.0, 2033254L, 600);
            Appliance Washer = new Appliance("Стиральная машина", 18299.0, 2036554L, 700);
            Appliance Kettle = new Appliance("Электрический чайник", 1290.0, 2032255L, 1200);

    apl.add(Toster);
    apl.add(Fridge);
    apl.add(Blender);
    apl.add(Washer);
    apl.add(Kettle);

    List<Clothes> clothes = new ArrayList<>();
            Clothes TShirt = new Clothes("Футболка", 500.0, 3024334L, (byte) 50, "Хлопок");
            Clothes SweetShot = new Clothes("Свитшот", 800.0, 3054332L, (byte) 55, "Полиэстр");
            Clothes Kimono = new Clothes("Кимоно", 1400.0, 3054345L, (byte) 70, "Хлопок");
            Clothes Coat = new Clothes("Пальто", 3400.0, 3054345L, (byte) 60, "Нейлон");
            Clothes Vest = new Clothes("Жилет", 2400.0, 3054645L, (byte) 55, "Бархат");

    clothes.add(TShirt);
    clothes.add(SweetShot);
    clothes.add(Kimono);
    clothes.add(Coat);
    clothes.add(Vest);
}
}
```

Так я сортировал только один Food List

```
System.out.println("\nСортировка Food");
    System.out.println("По имени:");
    Collections.sort(food, new Comparator<Food>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Food o1, Food o2) {
            return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        }
    });
    for(Food a: food)
        System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: вы выбрали самый плохой способ. попробуйте имплементировать в суперклассе интерфейс Comparable  , в который перенесите логику из вашего переопределенного метода. тогда метод sort можно вызывать без параметров для любой из коллекций, состоящих из экземпляров суперкласса либо его наследников

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Оказалось всё проще.
Объявил List:

```
...    
List<Product> all = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

добавил в List нужное, как и другие.

```
...
all.add(SCzCh1);
all.add(Slosos1);
all.add(Ekler1);
all.add(Borsh1);
all.add(Cake1);
...
```

Потом сделал сортировку на что и требовалось:

```
System.out.println("\nСортировка всех элементов");
    System.out.println("По имени:");
    Collections.sort(all, new Comparator<Product>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
            return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        }
    });
    for(Product a: all)
        System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: можно ещё проще: `Collections.sort(all, Comparator.comparing(Product::getName));`